# Include sparkline htmlwidget in datatable cells in a Shiny app, without resorting to (much) JavaScript

Tags: r, shiny, dt, htmlwidgets, sparklines

I am using the `sparkline` package to produce bar charts to place into cells of a `datatable` in a Shiny app. I've managed to produce the desired output in a standalone `datatable`, but when I place it into the Shiny app it doesn't work. It may have something to do with how `spk_add_deps()` identifies the htmlwidgets. I've tried moving the `spk_add_deps()` function around quite a bit and passing it various identifiers, and nothing worked.

I did find essentially the same question here [Render datatable with sparklines in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41477776/render-datatable-with-sparklines-in-shiny)
but the given solution (1) relies on writing the JavaScript code for the sparklines in a callback function (defeating the purpose of having the R `sparkline()` function) and (2) it seems that if the sparklines render in the viewer then we can't be all that far off from getting them to render in the Shiny app without having to write all that JavaScript.

Here's the demo:

```
# Preliminary, load packages and build a demo table with the sparkline code merged in
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(data.table)
library(sparkline)

## Create demo data sets
my_mtcars <- data.table(mtcars, keep.rownames = TRUE)
names(my_mtcars)[1] <- 'car_id'

set.seed(0)
data_for_sparklines <- data.table(car_id = rep(my_mtcars$car_id, 5),
                                  category = 1:5,
                                  value = runif(160))

sparkline_html <- data_for_sparklines[, .(sparkbar = spk_chr(value, type = 'bar')), by = 'car_id']
my_mtcars <- merge(my_mtcars, sparkline_html, by = 'car_id')
```

Now if I render the datatable on its own the sparkline bar graphs do appear:

```
spk_add_deps(datatable(my_mtcars, escape = FALSE))
```

[image: datatable showing sparkline bar charts]

But if I embed the same into a Shiny app that column is blank:

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput('myTable')
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$myTable <- renderDataTable(spk_add_deps(datatable(my_mtcars, escape = FALSE)))
}) 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: The htmlwidgets tend to only work for the JS package for which they were designed.  Unless someone specifically created a DT+sparkline widget in R, I think you're out of luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution, using the `htmlwidgets` package.

```
library(htmlwidgets)
```

Then instead of `spk_add_deps()` use `getDependency()` to load the sparkline dependencies in the Shiny UI function:

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  getDependency('sparkline'),
  dataTableOutput('myTable')
))
```

And for reasons I don't fully understand, add a callback in `renderDataTable()` to the HTMLwidgets `staticRender()` function:

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  staticRender_cb <- JS('function(){debugger;HTMLWidgets.staticRender();}') 
  output$myTable <- renderDataTable(my_mtcars,
                                    escape = FALSE,
                                    options = list(drawCallback = staticRender_cb))
})
```

But that's it, that's all it takes to get them to render in a Shiny app.

Comment: Brian, would you know by any chance how to display sparkline boxplots?

Answer (score 3):

FYI to anyone who comes across the initial code in the question and wants to use it *without* Shiny (as I did), that code only creates sparklines *on the first page of a table.* You need to add

```
options = list(
  fnDrawCallback = htmlwidgets::JS(
    '
function(){
  HTMLWidgets.staticRender();
}
'
  )
```

in the DT::datatable() code if you want the sparklines on all pages of the table.